# I was using selenium python to login

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping, account

I was using selenium (not chrome driver but orginal chrome) python to create a google account but google said to input a phone number and use the otp send to the number so i didn't do it and searched if any other person have done it but i found that it's not ok to do it so i backed off but the number otp verification is still needed so i created a normal account and used the phone number and otp and i thought it would be fixed but no whenever I go on to create a new account it always ask for otp how to fix it help would be appreciated thanks I am using windows 7 64 bit python 3 and normal selenium and also "\n"
**I don't think selenium-stealth would help**
You can ask for more info thanks in advance

Comment: Does this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver/70133896#70133896) helps you?

Comment: Let me see bro don't delete this comment thanks for your time

Comment: Do you have a chat group for selenium users in stack overflow