# Selenium python Chrome not working as intended

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

Even if we use :

```
options=Options() 
options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=orginal chrome path") 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

This above code need chromedriver. exe in to be in the current path where the file is even though it uses normal chrome so it this question is not duplicate and if we change the source code to use normal chrome.exe and it opens and the **chrome is being controlled by automated testing software** popup is closed but it can't do any further than that any solution
Thanks my os is windows 7 python3. 8.8 and selenium was installed by pip and chrome version is 96. Something any solu thanks also this question is related to this please answer both if you know question is [I was using selenium python to login](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70290064/17635725) you can ask for further info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that it won't work as selenium need chromedriver to work